# Как наиболее правильней и корректней вернуть более одного значения в методе? С#

Tags: c#, return, value

Мне надо чтоб метод вернул четыре значения один bool, один string и два float. Я делаю это с помощью `Dictionary<bool, string>` Но Dictionary мне кажется создан для списков и этот вариант я думаю не совсем правильный. Как обычное вы делаете, когда функция должна вернуть более одного значения? Как это сделать правильней и эффективней?

Comment: В идеале - написать свой класс для этого

Comment: можно вернуть массив или же принять параметры по ссылке и изменять их в функции

Comment: @Lofectr .  (int x1, int x2, out int x3, out int x4) Нашёл уже ...спасибо за совет

Comment: @tym32167 написать свой класс. Я понял совет, но это эффективней чем принять параметры по ссылке? ... Что наиболее оптимально? В плане кода второй вариант кажется более оптимальным

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Если эти параметры взаимосвязаны (а они, скорее всего,  взаимосвязаны, раз возвращаются из одного метода)  то лучше объединить в класс.  Это будет проще и читать,  и сопровождать.

Comment: Запомните - если вы пишете код в команде на работе и вашей программой будут пользоваться и поддерживать, то это означает, что ваш код будут читать очень много раз. Поэтому самое важное не писать код оптимальным, а писать код так, чтобы он был понятен людям, которые будут его читать. Поэтому если вы возвращаете 4 значения, желательно, чтобы у этих значений были имена и типы, как у свойств класса. Более того, вы даже можете такому классу прописать нужный конструктор, чтобы, например, метод не мог вернуть только 2 значения или три, а обязательно 4.

Comment: @tym32167 Если не сложно и есть время можно в ответе привести код ? Как написать конструктор, чтоб обязательно вернул 4 значения

Comment: это просто конструктор с 4 параметрами, один параметр на одно свойство. И прямо в конструкторе можно проверять, что строки не пустые, что сслыки не нулевые, что числа не отрицательные и т.д., то есть если кто то попробует создать экземпляр такого класса, он обязан будет отправить туда 4 значения, и если хоть одно из них не подходит под вашу логику, то класс моментально это поймает и создаст исключение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотрим вариант номер 1 - простейший массив

```
public object[] GetPerson1()
{
    return new object[] { "Vasya", 120, new DateTime(1980, 1, 1) };
}
```

Все вроде ок, но вот пробема. Если кто то вызывает вашу функцию, ему надо догадываться, что это за значения вы передаете. То есть без вашего кода, например, не понять, что такое 120.

Второй вариант уже лучше

```
public Dictionary<string, object> GetPerson2()
{
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "name", "Vasya" }, { "height", 120 }, { "birthday", new DateTime(1980, 1, 1) }};
}
```

Но тут, чтобы пользователю функции понять назначения переменных, не достаточно просто вызвать функцию - придется проитерировать словарь или снова идти читать ваш код.

Следующий вариант ещё немного лучше

```
public (string name, int height, DateTime birthDate) GetPerson3()
{
    return ("Vasya", 120, new DateTime(1980, 1,1));
}
```

Но в этом случае, как и во всех предыдущих, есть 2 минуса: значения никак не валидированы (то есть вы легко можете отправить значение роста человека отрицательным или указать ему пустое имя), второе - вызывающий код может просто поменять эти значения и все сломать, например

```
var person3 = GetPerson3(); 
person3.height = -100;
```

Потому, если вы хотите делать вещи правльно, но сначала определим класс человека

```
public sealed class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int Height { get; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; }

    public Person(string name, int height, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));
        if (height <= 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(height));
        if (birthDate.Year < 1900) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(birthDate));

        Name = name;
        Height = height;
        BirthDate = birthDate;      
    }
}
```

Вы видите тут 3 вещи:

1. Входящих параметров три. Нельзя создать экземпляр такого класса, но с 2 параметрами или 4. Только 3.
2. Каждый параметр валидируется, то есть нельзя создать экземпляр с неверными значениями параметров.
3. Класс только на чтение. После создания экземпляра уже нельзя его поменять.

Ну и как бонус, программисту, который будет вызывать ваш метод, нет смысла смотреть на код вашего метода, какой бы он ни был. В принципе, он даже на код класса Person может не глядеть - все поля ему подскажет Intellisense. Поменять созданный класс он тоже не сможет, что уменьшет количество ошибок в разы, хотя и увеличивает кодичество кода.